# Role of oversampling within resampling / pitch modification

Tags: filters, audio, lowpass-filter, interpolation, resampling

I'm working on a pitch modification plugin involving resampling, and want the quality to be as high as possible.

I currently use windowed sinc interpolation and lowpass filter where required.

I noticed some pitch modification plugins offer an "oversampling" option, but I don't understand its purpose.

To me it seems oversampling would give similar results to windowed sinc interpolation.

I also don't understand where oversampling takes place in the order of operations (whether it occurs before or after lowpassing, etc.)

Any help or articles on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you be more specific about which pitch-shifting plugins or products have this oversampling option?  I also want to know exactly what they mean.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Specifically GForm, a plugin by GVST (https://www.gvst.co.uk/beta.htm). I imagine it has to do with accuracy of the lowpass filter